# debian 9 terminal cannot change to su

Tags: linux, debian, fish

I installed debian stretch yesterday. I installed fish shell . I change the default shell to fish by the following

```
su chsh -s 'which fish'
```

Then again enter the this command

```
su chsh -s `which fish`
```

Now after I restart the PC I encountered the following error while using "su"

```
sathish@localhost ~> su
Password: 
Cannot execute which fish: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Unless you have a user with name `chsh`, the first two commands will fail...

Comment: How to solve this @heemayl

Comment: What is your goal? Set `fish` as the default (login) shell for `root`?

Comment: Yes I need to set fish as my default shell

Comment: _You_ meaning `root` or _satish_?

Comment: the problem is with root only . In sathish its working fine

Comment: THe problem is that you used `which`. This `whichcraft` See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BadUtils#which

Comment: Install `sudo` then follow the instruction on Askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/a/848038/498780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Since I'm unable to comment. So posting here)

1. Change user to su

> `$ su`
>
> (Then enter password)

2. Type

> `# chsh [username]`
>
> In your case:
>
> `# chsh root`

3. Enter login shell `/usr/bin/fish`
4. That's it. Logout and login again. Should work

Comment: when I enter the su and after enter password it shows ` sathish@localhost ~> su
Password: 
Cannot execute which fish: No such file or directory `

Comment: If you installed fish using package manager, the login shell is linked from /usr/bin/fish. Simply enter this when prompted by chsh

Comment: I understand you are unable to login as su right? In that case you might want to have a look at `/etc/passwd` file. See for `root` user (The first line generally). For me it's `/bin/bash`. Edit it to `/usr/bin/fish`.
To edit - `su -c 'nano /etc/passwd'`. When done, save and exit.
 Logout and login.

Comment: Please consider marking this answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

From comments: it is clear that you want to change the login shell for user `root` to `fish`. Do:

```
sudo chsh -s "$(which fish)" root
```

Or simply:

```
sudo chsh -s "$(which fish)"
```

You might have to put absolute path to `fish` in `/etc/shells` if not present already (usually done by `postinst` maintainer script while installation of the package).

---

If you don't have `sudo` installed, you have bigger problems to solve IMHO. Anyway, here is the way to do this using `su`:

```
su root -c 'chsh -s "$(which fish)"'
```

You need `root`'s password in this case (as usual).

Comment: I dont have sudo installed. I tried `sathish@localhost /> su chsh -s /usr/bin/fish root
No passwd entry for user 'chsh' `

Comment: Could you please say where the configuration file for root terminal is stored

Comment: @SathishKumar Check my edits...

Comment: Thank You . But it not works same error exists and error throws ' sathish@localhost:~$ su root -c 'chsh -s "$(which fish)"'
Password: 
Cannot execute which fish `

Comment: @SathishKumar you can't rely on `which`. Either use `command -v fish` or `type -p fish`. Forget everything about `which`.